# Transforming into a first order system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I cannot convert my original system into one of first order and I'm trying so hard, please, could anyone help me? Thanks in advance!

My system is:

$u''(t)=\frac{v(t)}{1+t^2}-\sin(r(t))$

$v''(t)=\frac{-u(t)}{1+t^2}+\cos(r(t))$

Where

$r(t)=\sqrt{u'(t)^2+v'(t)^2}$

Comment: What did you try, what was your most hopeful approach to date?

Comment: @LutzLehmann naming for example x=u, and y=u' but i get confused and I don't know if I'm doing the correct change of variables

Comment: @LutzLehmann and the $\sin$ doesn't help me, because I don't know if name it another variable or try to put it in matrix form, I'm so lost

Comment: Introducing the first derivatives is a correct step. You seem to have problems with the naming scheme, you could just try the universal $(y_1,y_2,y_3,y_4)$. Note that a first-order system need not be linear, esp. if the original higher order system is non-linear.

Comment: @LutzLehmann if you could help me, putting it in matrix form it would be helpful because I cannot do it by myself, sorry

Comment: There is no matrix form for a non-linear function, just a vector valued function, or a system of non-linear functions.

Comment: Please [edit](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3509941/edit) your question text to move the comments on what you tried and what you think the result should look like into the question. At the moment, it contains only the task and not your specific question/problem description about the task.

Comment: Wolfram Alpha and Mathematica failed to solve this one analytically. You may have to resort to numerical solution.

Answer (score 0):

The aim of this task is to get a system $\vec y\,'(x)=\vec F(t,\vec y(x))$ that fits the general ODE theory and also the format that a general numerical ODE solver would demand as input. As your original system has two second order equations, the state vector $y$ is 4-dimensional. Next one would have to fix the order of the 4 components, one could have $\vec y=(u,u',v,v')$ having the first derivative next to the function, or having the functions first, then the derivatives, $\vec y=(u,v,u',v')$. What remains is to replace the original variables and derivatives by the components of $\vec y$.

It sometimes helps focusing on the essentials by formulating the function to pass to a numerical ODE solver. In `python` this could look like

```
def system(t,y):
    u, v, du, dv = y;
    r = hypot(du,dv);
    a = 1/(1+t**2);
    return [ du, dv, a*v - sin(r), -a*u + cos(r) ];
```

or in matlab

```
function doty = system(t,y)
    r = sqrt(y(1)^2+y2^2);
    a = 1/(1+t^2);
    doty = [ y(3); y(4); a*y(2)-sin(r); -a*y(1)+cos(r) ];
end
```

Comment: I don't know python,for a numerical ODE solver I'm more into octave...

Comment: In matlab-like environments, the tuple assignment does not exist (there is a strange looking work-around, array->cells->tuple). You would have to replace `u` with `y(1)`, ..., `dv` with `y(4)` in all occurrences, in the main the structure of the first order system function remains the same. The point is you get a system $\vec y'(x)=\vec F(t,\vec y(x))$.